# Python code for replacing texts not working

Tags: python, string, python-2.7, replace

My code is this.

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("aaaa.txt",inplace=1):
     map_dict = {'\N':'999999999', '[':'(', '＆':'&'}
     line = ''.join(map_dict.get(c,c) for c in line)
     print line,
```

I experimented this with aaaa.txt but it's simply not replacing anything.

A simpler code that I know works is

```
import fileinput
for line in fileinput.FileInput("aaaa.txt",inplace=1):
    line = line.replace("\N","999999999")
    print line,
```

But I want to make the first code work, because it replaces multiple things.

Comment: refer to this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484156/is-str-replace-replace-ad-nauseam-a-standard-idiom-in-python

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`\N` is two character string. (same as `'\\N'`)

```
>>> '\N'
'\\N'
>>> len('\N')
2
```

But iterating a string yields single character strings.

```
>>> for ch in 'ab\Ncd':
...     print ch
...
a
b
\
N
c
d
```

The code never replace `\` followed by `N`.

How about call replace multiple times?

```
for old, new in map_dict.iteritems():
    line = line.replace(old, new)
```

Comment: Thank you. But the problem is that the program can't do other replacing jobs like '[':'('    /N alone doesn't seem to be the source of the problem.

Comment: @user3123767, Did you try the way I suggested? (with `print`)

Comment: @user3123767, You should put `print` statement after the `for` loop.

Comment: It says unexpected indent. So I changed indentation. Then it says unindent doesn't match any outer indentation level.

Comment: Thank you. I marked your answer. By the way why didn't the first code in my question work?

Comment: @user3123767, You should dedent the `print` statement. BTW `print` statement with trailing `,` print additional space.