# Pythonic way to replace chars

Tags: python, replace, character-replacement

I want to replace some characters in a string using a pythonic approach.

```
A -> T
C -> G
G -> C
T -> A
```

Example:

> AAATCGATTGAT

will transform into

> TTTAGCTAACTA

What I did:

```
def swap(string):
    string = re.sub('A', 'aux', string)
    string = re.sub('T', 'A', string)
    string = re.sub('aux', 'T', string)
    string = re.sub('C', 'aux', string)
    string = re.sub('G', 'C', string)
    string = re.sub('aux', 'G', string)

    return string
```

It worked great, but i'm looking for a more pythonic way to reach that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a refactoring of <del>the currently accepted-</del> *Chepner's deleted* answer which only calls `maketrans` once.

```
tt = str.maketrans({"A":"T", "C":"G", "G":"C", "T": "A"})
for s1 in "AGACAT", "TAGGAC", "ACTAGAA":
    print(s1.translate(tt))
```

Perhaps also point out that you can chain the result from `replace`, though this is still clumsy and inefficient:

```
def acgtgca(s1):
    return s1.replace(
        "A", "\ue0fa").replace(
        "G", "\ue0fb").replace(
        "C", "G").replace(
        "T", "A").replace(
        "\ue0fb", "C").replace(
        "\ue0fa", "T")
```

This avoids using "aux" as a special marker in favor of two arbitrary characters out of the Unicode [Private Use Area](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_Use_Areas).

But again, the `maketrans` method is both neater and more efficient.

Comment: Maybe see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2484156/is-str-replace-replace-ad-nauseam-a-standard-idiom-in-python which has a nice alternative using `reduce`

Answer (score 5):

Use a dictionary with a comprehension and `str.join`:

```
translateDict = {
  "A" : "T",
  "C" : "G",
  "G" : "C",
  "T" : "A"
}

s1 = "AAATCGATTGAT"
reconstructed = "".join(translateDict.get(s, s) for s in s1)
```

Here you have the [live example](https://repl.it/repls/ConsciousJuvenileDefragment)

Note the use of [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=get#dict.get); in case the letter is not in the dictionary we just let it as it was.

As @bravosierra99 suggests, you can also simply use [`str.translate`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate):

```
reconstructed = s1.translate(string.maketrans(translateDict))
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. That's what im looking for <3

Comment: if you are going to do translation, then you should do it properly.  https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/methods/string/translate

Comment: @bravosierra99 Your link is unreadable on mobile (big ad with close button outside the screen). Maybe link to the official documentation or a relevant Stack Overflow question instead?

Comment: @tripleee, you have the link to the official documentation in the answer ;)